# NFS mount failed after migrating Linux NFS server: "RPC: Rpcbind failure - RPC: Unable to receive"

Tags: linux, nfs, rpc

NFS client: Solaris 8

NFS server: RHEL 7.3 - a virtual machine originally hosted on HyperView, recently migrated to VMWare.

NFS used to work well in the previous configuration. With the virtual Linux host moved onto the new platform, any mount attempt on the Solaris NFS client now yields:

```
nfs mount: (hostname): : RPC: Rpcbind failure - RPC: Unable to receive
nfs mount: retrying: /(filesystem)
```

where hostname is the Linux NFS server host name.

On the NFS server:

- Exportfs shows the correctly exported/shared file systems.
- The following processes are running, maybe some daemon is missing. I have selected the processes I thought relevant (those containing "nfs" or "rpc"):

> root      1888     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:00 [nfsd4_callbacks]
>
> root      1922     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:00 [nfsd]
>
> root      1925     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:00 [nfsd]
>
> root      1926     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:00 [nfsd]
>
> root      1928     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:00 [nfsd]
>
> root      1931     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:00 [nfsd]
>
> root      1932     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:00 [nfsd]
>
> root      1934     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:01:21 [nfsd]
>
> root      1937     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:13:21 [nfsd]
>
> root      4617     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:00 [nfsiod]
>
> root       973     1  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:00
>   /usr/sbin/rpc.idmapd
>
> rpcuser   1357     1  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/rpc.statd
>   --no-notify
>
> root      1638     1  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:00
>   /usr/sbin/rpc.mountd

The Linux machine has been moved over as is. No configuration items were ever touched. I don't know whether changing the hosting platform can be relevant to the virtual machine's rpc functionality.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edited to add: there is no rpc.nfsd process currently running.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it - it works!

Indeed, some daemons were missing. After some digging, I found that these services are not automatically started upon boot:

> systemctl start rpcbind
>
> systemctl start nfs-lock
>
> systemctl enable nfs-lock